# Degree of the variety of singular points of a map

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $V\subset \mathbb{A}^n$ be an irreducible variety defined over a perfect field $k$. Let $\phi:V\to \mathbb{A}^d$ be a dominant morphism, where $d=\dim V$. Then all singular points of $\phi$ lie on a proper subvariety $W$ of $V$. Write $\phi(\vec{x}) = (\phi_1(\vec{x}),\dotsc,\phi_d(\vec{x}))$. Can we bound the number of components $W_i$ of $W$ and their degree in terms of $n$, $d$, the degree of $\phi_i$ and the degree of $W$? What is the best bound known?

---

Here is an attempt. There are polynomials $P_1,\dotsc,P_{n-d}$ on $n$ variables such that $V$ is a component of the variety defined by $P_1(\vec{x}) = \dotsc = P_{n-d}(\vec{x})=0$. Define an $n$-by-$n$ matrix $A(\vec{x})$ by placing the Jacobian of $\phi$ on top of the Jacobian of the map defined by $P(\vec{x}) = (P_1(\vec{x}),\dotsc,P_{n-d}(\vec{x}))$. Let $S$ be the variety defined by $\det A(\vec{x})=0$. Then $W$ is the intersection of $S$ and $V$, and thus $\sum_i \deg(W_i) \leq \deg(S) \deg(V)$, by generalized Bézout. The degree of $\deg(S)$ is bounded by $\prod_{1\leq i\leq d} (\deg(\phi_i)-1) \prod_{1\leq i\leq n-d} (\deg P_i - 1)$.

The problem is that I do not know how to bound the second product here. It would stand to sense if one could always choose $P_1,\dotsc,P_{n-d}$ so that $\prod_{1\leq i\leq n-d} \deg P_i \leq \deg V$, but I do not know that for a fact.

Comment: What is $W$? it is just a sub-variety that contains the singular points?

Comment: Yes, a proper sub-variety that contains the singular points.